# How to obtain traffic light location information

Tags: here-api

In [HERE documentation](https://developer.here.com/develop/rest-apis) they describe the Platform Data Extension API as capable of providing traffic lights information.
[image]

I have not been able to find any attribute of any layer that may represent this information.

Am I missing something? I have looked in the available attributes

> https://pde.cit.api.here.com/1/doc/attributes.html?&app_id={APP_ID}&app_code={APP_CODE}&region=WEU&release=LATEST

and in the available layers

> https://pde.cit.api.here.com/1/doc/layers.html?&app_id={APP_ID}&app_code={APP_CODE}&region=WEU&release=LATEST

and I could not find any hint to Traffic Lights information.

How can I obtain the traffic information(mainly position)?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you provide more information on what are you exactly looking for? With the above example you had provided the traffic sign layer is available. https://pde.cit.api.here.com/1/tile.json?region=WEU&release=LATEST&layer=TRAFFIC_SIGN_FC1&level=9&tilex=496&tiley=358&app_id={APP_ID}&app_code={APP_CODE}

Answer (score 0):

**Filter Only Metainfo for Road Signs**
Adding the parameter filter to the request obtains only metainfo for road sign labels and excludes all other kinds of labels from the JSON response. This is useful in case of tiles that contain a lot of different labels as the one requested below:

> https://2.base.maps.ls.hereapi.com/maptile/2.1/maptile/newest/normal.day/11/1102/673/256/png8
>   ?apiKey={YOUR_API_KEY}

For more information, please refer :

```
developer.here.com/documentation/map-tile/dev_guide/topics/example-meta-roadsign.html
```